# Excel - Dynamic counting of different lists based on a cell value

Tags: excel, counting

I'm having a problem with counting the number of elements in a different list based on the name of said list in a cell.
Before asking here I tried some things by myself such as using INDEX and CELL functions but the results are not the one I expect.

So I have several lists of items I put in different tests and my objective is to count how many times I tested an item.

```
        |   Item    |
        | A | B | C |
 test 1 |   | x |   |
 test 2 | x | x |   |
 test 3 |   |   | x |
```

And so on. I created lists named A, B and C and I want to know how many times I have tested some of them based on the name of a list I put in a cell.

Since =COUNTA(B) gives the expected result, I tried to combine that with the functions INDEX and CELL :

```
= COUNTA(INDEX(G3,1))  

= COUNTA(CELL("contents",G3))
```

But I only get a returned value of 1. I hope my question is clear enough, because I couldn't find anything like that. To help visualize my problem, I have added a picture.

Picture of the problem:  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this formula:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET($A$4:$A$21,0,MATCH(G3,$B$3:$E$3,0)))
```

It will count the number of non-empty cells in the column holding the name entered in `G3`, bit it starts at row 4 to exclude the headers from the count.